# Jquery UI sortable not working after context change (master detail <select>)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

## What I've trying to accomplish:

Select a class from the dropdown to see which persons are in the selected class, and be able to sort them.

## My problem:

when I change my selected Class. the "ui-sortable-handle" stops being emitted

## My Code:

```
<select data-bind="options: Classes, optionsText: 'Name', value: SelectedClass"></select>
<div data-bind="with: SelectedClass">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Persons" id="selectable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've created <kbd>**[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexintime/5x0ohsc1/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when knockout rerenders the list with the different items, it just puts it's own plain html in place again.  jQueryUI knows nothing about them as it's happened after your call to `.sortable`.  Luckily, there is a [knockout sortable binding](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) to work directly with jQuery sortable.